# How to read one filesystem from a whole disk image file?

Tags: linux, partition, virtual-machine, file-transfer

I ran these commands:

```
VBoxManage clonehd d6b9f0a5-98df-48ca-83c8-91a0809ec349 --format RAW Debian.raw
sudo dd if=~/.VirtualBox/HardDisks/Debian.raw of=/dev/sda5
```

When I try to mount the partition, I get this complaint:

```
EXT4-fs (sda5): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
```

Now I know that the VM had an ext4 partition. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @ciro the first link you posted is a link to this post itself. Can you explain what is the usefulness of that in addition to wasting time of anyone clicking on that?

Comment: @ciro If those three include selfreferences as well, you should delete those as well.

Answer (score 8):

Your image is a disk image, not a filesystem image. The filesystem is on a partition inside that image (unless you did something really unusual). You can confirm this by running `file Debian.raw` and `fdisk -l Debian.raw`.

The easiest way to access this partition is to associate it with a loop device. If you can, make sure your `loop` driver supports and is loaded with the `max_parts` option; you may need to run `rmmod loop; modprobe loop max_part=63`. Then associate the disk image with a loop device, and voilà:

```
losetup -fs Debian.raw     # prints /dev/loop0 (or some other number)
mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt    # 0 as above, 1 is the partition number
```

If you can't get the loop driver to use partitions, you need to find out the offset of the partition in the disk image. Run `fdisk -lu Debian.raw` to list the partitions and find out its starting sector S (a sector is 512 bytes). Then tell `losetup` you want the loop device to start at this offset:

```
fdisk -lu Debian.raw  # note starting sector $S
losetup -fs -o $(($S * 512)) Debian.raw
mount /dev/loop0 /mnt  # /dev/loop0 or whatever losetup prints
```

If you want to copy the partition from the VM image to your system, determine its starting (`$S`) and ending (`$E`) offsets with `fdisk -lu` as above. Then copy just the partition:

```
<Debian.raw tail -c +$((512*$S)) | dd of=/dev/sda5 bs=4M
```

(If the source and the destination are not on the same disk, don't bother with `dd`, just redirect `tail`'s output to `/dev/sda5`. If they are on the same disk, `dd` with a large `bs` parameter is a lot faster.)

Comment: I'm attempting this exact procedure, and I've gotten the loop mount to work, but after using tail and dd, mount still cannot find a filesystem on the raw device. any ideas?

Comment: @TREE: Did you use the loop driver's partition support (`/dev/loop0p1`), or a user-specified offset (`losetup -o`)? What is the output of `<Debian.raw file -`, of `<Debian.raw tail -c +$((512*s)) | file -`, or `file -` on any relevant intermediate stage?

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04, `proc` is a built-in module, so `rmmod` fails. Editing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` on `/etc/default/grub` works: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87189/32558

Comment: Excellent answer, helped me to mount a raspberry pi raspbian image https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

Answer (score 2):

**losetup 2.21 -P option**

```
losetup -P -f --show my.img
```

Creates one `/dev/loopXpY` per partition.

Advantage: executable pre-installed in many distros (util-linux package).

Disadvantage: quite recent option, not present in Ubuntu 14.04.

**`losetup -P` automation**

Usage:

```
$ los my.img
/dev/loop0
/mnt/loop0p1
/mnt/loop0p2

$ ls /mnt/loop0p1
/whatever
/files
/youhave
/there

$ sudo losetup -l
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE                                                                                      DIO
/dev/loop1         0      0         0  0 /full/path/to/my.img

$ # Cleanup.
$ losd 0
$ ls /mnt/loop0p1
$ ls /dev | grep loop0
loop0
```

Source:

```
los() (
  img="$1"
  dev="$(sudo losetup --show -f -P "$img")"
  echo "$dev"
  for part in "$dev"?*; do
    if [ "$part" = "${dev}p*" ]; then
      part="${dev}"
    fi
    dst="/mnt/$(basename "$part")"
    echo "$dst"
    sudo mkdir -p "$dst"
    sudo mount "$part" "$dst"
  done
)
losd() (
  dev="/dev/loop$1"
  for part in "$dev"?*; do
    if [ "$part" = "${dev}p*" ]; then
      part="${dev}"
    fi
    dst="/mnt/$(basename "$part")"
    sudo umount "$dst"
  done
  sudo losetup -d "$dev"
)
```

**kpartx**

```
sudo apt-get install kpartx
losetup -fs my.raw
sudo kpartx -a my.img
ls /dev/mapper
```

Output:

```
/dev/mapper/loop0
/dev/mapper/loop0p1
```

where `loop0p1` is the first partition, so we can do:

```
mkdir -p d
sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop0p1 d
```

Advantage of this method: works on Ubuntu 14.04 without rebooting.