# Mouting a kvm qemu disk image with multiple partitions

Tags: mount, virtualization, kvm, qemu

I am trying to mount a KVM-qemu disk image with this command: 
`sudo mount -o loop,offset=32256 centos6.img /mnt/centos6`. But it shows this error: `you must specify filesystem type`. As I have more partitions in my disk image I tried [this solution](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/mounting-a-qemu-created-root-disk-image-377212/#post1921883). But that too gives same error.

Here is the output of `fdisk -ul centos6.img`:

```
Disk centos6.img: 0 MB, 0 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 0 cylinders, total 0 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0001da69

      Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
centos6.img1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
centos6.img2         1026048    20971519     9972736   8e  Linux LVM
Partition 2 has different physical/logical endings:
     phys=(1023, 254, 63) logical=(1305, 106, 17)
```

Comment: The answer here solved my issue.
http://serverfault.com/questions/287070/how-to-mount-virtual-machines-lvm-partition-on-kvm-host

Comment: As I couldn't boot my vm image I wanted to edit the `inittab` file. But editing it hasn't solved the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
kpartx -av cento.img
```

And mounting the loop device created in `/dev/mapper`:

```
sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt/destination
```

Answer (score 1):

2048 (starting sector) times 512 (sector size) is 1048576. So you should run

```
sudo mount -o loop,offset=1048576 centos6.img /mnt/centos6
```

The reason for the error message you got is that you told the kernel to look for a filesystem at some random unoccupied point on the disk. So it told you it didn't recognize a filesystem there.

See [Reading a filesystem from a whole disk image](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9099/reading-a-filesystem-from-a-whole-disk-image) for background.

You might try [libguestfs](http://libguestfs.org/), which can mount many VM disk images automagically.