# How to create a formatted partition image file from scratch?

Tags: linux, partition, loop-device

I need to create filesystem with just one partition from nothing (`/dev/zero`). 
I tried this sequence of commands:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=mountedImage.img bs=512 count=131072
fdisk mountedImage.img
    n
    p 
    2048
    131072
```

Basically, I need to create 64MB image file filled with zeroes. Then I use `fdisk` to add a new partition for new filesystem (which should finally be FAT32), starting at sector `2048` and using all remaining sectors.

```
losetup /dev/loop1 mountedImage.img
mkfs -t vfat /dev/loop1
```

But here I'm hitting problems. If I set up a `loop` device and format it using `mkfs -t vfat`, partition table is overwritten and filesystem (FAT32) is placed to disk. I don't need whole disk formatted with FAT32, I just need my primary partition to be so.

Does anybody know how can I format only one partition of raw disk image, not whole image?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by setting up a loop device and post your entire `mkfs` call. I had to read your post 3 times to understand your problem. While I can't help you, I'm interessted in why you create an image file(!) but still want to leave the first n "sectors" unused.

Comment: Ok, edited it. I want to leave first n sectors (what's wrong with sectors?) unused, as I need to place my bootloaders somewhere.

Comment: [Crossposted](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333875/creating-filesystem-from-nothing)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek There are considerations that apply to some Linux distributions but not Ubuntu (it matters whether `loop` is a module or built into the kernel), so I think it is useful for each site to have its version of the question and I voted to reopen.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Personally, I feel AskUbuntu is more specific than Unix & Linux, so if a question is cross-posted to both, unless there are specific reasons to close here it's the one on AskUbuntu that should be closed as cross-posted if they were posted close in time to each other, regardless of where it was posted "first" (possibly with a mention of Ubuntu/non-Ubuntu answers here). Here it has an accepted answer, which the one on AskUbuntu does not, which strongly favors keeping this one open IMO. I don't have the rep to vote to close on AskUbuntu but am voting to reopen the question here.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Didn't notice we had an accepted answer here, I messaged the AU mods to close theirs

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/518554/how-do-you-create-and-partition-a-raw-disk-image

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If on Linux, when loading the `loop` module, make sure you pass a `max_part` option to the module so that the loop devices are partitionable.

Check the current value:

```
cat /sys/module/loop/parameters/max_part
```

If it's 0:

```
modprobe -r loop # unload the module
modprobe loop max_part=31
```

To make this setting persistent, add the following line to `/etc/modprobe.conf` or to a file in `/etc/modprobe.d` if that directory exists on your system:

```
options loop max_part=31
```

If `modprobe -r loop` fails because “Module loop is builtin”, you'll need to add `loop.max_part=31` to your kernel command line and reboot. If your bootloader is Grub2, add to it to the value of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in `/etc/default/grub` and update GRUB using `update-grub`.

Now, you can create a partitionable loop device:

```
truncate -s 64M file # no need to fill it with zeros, just make it sparse
fdisk file # create partitions
losetup /dev/loop0 file
mkfs.vfat /dev/loop0p1 # for the first partition.
mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt/
```

Unmount after using and detach loop device

```
umount /mnt
losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

(note that you need a relatively recent version of Linux).

Comment: FATAL: Module loop is builtin, can this be solved installing lastest version of ubuntu (I have 12.04)?

Comment: If is builtin just no needed to modprobe, pass the `loop.max_part=31` to the kernel command line

Comment: Ah I see, if you've a recent kernel and you pass the max_part the offset and the sizelimit aren't needed at all

Comment: Hmm, kernel command line, too difficult for me. Still thanks, accept.

Comment: Is it `loop.maxpart=31` or `loop.max_part=31` on the kernel command line?

Answer (score 4):

`losetup /dev/loop0 file -o 1048576 --sizelimit limit`

Offset specified should be in bytes (1048576 = 2048 sectors * 512 bytes per sector).

`mount -o loop,offset=1048576,sizelimit=limit`

For more information see [losetup](http://linux.die.net/man/8/losetup) and [mount](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount).

Comment: Hmm, offset, this should work. And what if I had more partitions on it?

Comment: I guess one loop = one partition = one offset.

Comment: uhm, and is there an option to specify also the size, so I could limit it and place there more partitions?

Comment: Sorry my fault to create a new answer with a partial solution, the right answer is from @"Stephane Chazelas", he can just add the offset and sizelimit options (then I'll delete mine)

Comment: No let it be here, or mine +1 will go nowhere.

Answer (score 3):

A simple example using ext4 file system and GPT partitioned image.

```
truncate -s 100MiB mountedImage.img
```

Create a GPT Table

```
parted mountedImage.img mklabel gpt
```

Create Partition P1

```
parted mountedImage.img mkpart primary ext4 2MiB 30MiB
```

Create Partition P2

```
parted mountedImage.img mkpart primary ext4 30MiB 60MiB
```

Create Partition P3

```
parted mountedImage.img mkpart primary ext4 60MiB 99MiB
```

Say you are using the loop device `/dev/loop1` (it's always better to use `sudo losetup -f` to get a free loop device):

`losetup /dev/loop1 mountedImage.img` -> should enumerate the partitions to create devices like `/dev/loop1px` for each partition `x` represents the partition number.

[use] `mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop1px` -> to be done on the partition number `x`

[and not] `mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop1`  -> will only delete the partition table

Note: The partitions from the image are visible in loop device only if the module is configured for multi partition.

Please refer to the link to my blog, [Creating a GPT Partitioned image from Scratch in Linux](https://tvsarathy.blogspot.com/2021/11/creating-gpt-partioned-image-from.html), for creating partitioned image from scratch using GPT.

Answer (score 2):

The following procedures allow you to mount the partitions of the image to modify them.

**losetup 2.21 -P option**

```
losetup -P -f --show my.img
```

Creates one `/dev/loopXpY` per partition.

Advantage: executable pre-installed in many distros (util-linux package).

Disadvantage: quite recent option, not present in Ubuntu 14.04.

**`losetup -P` automation**

Usage:

```
$ los my.img
/dev/loop0
/mnt/loop0p1
/mnt/loop0p2

$ ls /mnt/loop0p1
/whatever
/files
/youhave
/there

$ sudo losetup -l
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE                                                                                      DIO
/dev/loop1         0      0         0  0 /full/path/to/my.img

$ # Cleanup.
$ losd 0
$ ls /mnt/loop0p1
$ ls /dev | grep loop0
loop0
```

Source:

```
los() (
  img="$1"
  dev="$(sudo losetup --show -f -P "$img")"
  echo "$dev"
  for part in "$dev"?*; do
    if [ "$part" = "${dev}p*" ]; then
      part="${dev}"
    fi
    dst="/mnt/$(basename "$part")"
    echo "$dst"
    sudo mkdir -p "$dst"
    sudo mount "$part" "$dst"
  done
)
losd() (
  dev="/dev/loop$1"
  for part in "$dev"?*; do
    if [ "$part" = "${dev}p*" ]; then
      part="${dev}"
    fi
    dst="/mnt/$(basename "$part")"
    sudo umount "$dst"
  done
  sudo losetup -d "$dev"
)
```

**kpartx**

```
sudo apt-get install kpartx
losetup -fs my.raw
sudo kpartx -a my.img
ls /dev/mapper
```

Output:

```
/dev/mapper/loop0
/dev/mapper/loop0p1
```

where `loop0p1` is the first partition, so we can do:

```
mkdir -p d
sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop0p1 d
```

Advantage of this method: works on Ubuntu 14.04 without rebooting.