# Error mounting .img file

Tags: linux-mint, mount, disk-image

In Linux Mint 18.2 when I choose "Open With Disk Image Mounter" in a right click menu on an .img file I get following error:

> Unable to mount OS
>
> Error mounting /dev/loop1 at /media/mint/OS: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999" "/dev/loop1" "/media/mint/OS"' exited with non-zero exit status 21:
>   ntfs-3g-mount: mount failed: Permission denied

("OS" is a label of a drive from which this image was created.) I have another .img file (also with NTFS in it) and I receive similar error when I try to mount it. Both files were created with a built-in Linux Mint "Disks" utility. If it helps, they are both 100Gb+ in size and have brackets in their names.

How do I fix this error? Or maybe there is a way to mount or view their contents with different tools?

Comment: Are you prompted for authentication when you try to mount it? Have you tried mounting it from the command line as `root`?

Comment: @NasirRiley No, I'm not prompted for authentication. I tried to copy command line from this error message into terminal adding "sudo" before it, but I still get an error:

"> Failed to read bootsector (size=0) Failed to sync device /dev/loop1:
> Input/output error Failed to mount '/dev/loop1': Invalid argument The
> device '/dev/loop1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS. Maybe the wrong
> device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a partition (e.g.
> /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?"

Comment: Create a mountpoint such as /mnt/img and then try this: `mount -o loop /path/to/file.img /mnt/img` You may get a message of `mounting read-only` but it should mount the `img` file

Comment: Is the image of a filesystem or a disk? You can check with `file /path/to/image` If it's a disk image, you can use `kpartx` to create block device files from the partitions within the image; Then you can mount the correct block device. You can also use the libguestfs shell to mount a disk image.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to mount a **disk** image (with the image including a partition table and possibly multiple partitions instead of just one partition). Try using the loop module with

```
sudo losetup -f file.img
```

The NTFS formatted partition(s) should then show up in the file manager.

You may need to allow partitions on the loop device explicitly (see [How to create a formatted partition image file from scratch?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87183/how-to-create-a-formatted-partition-image-file-from-scratch)).