# Generating a .img from tarball: The /dev/loop devices

Tags: loop-device, disk-image

I'm trying to make a .img from a tarball using the following script I found:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Packages required
# dosfstools parted 
# Can be run on any Linux system
# loop.max_part=15 must be in kernel cmdline (cmdline.txt for rpi)
# then reboot

echo "creating image to fit on 2Gb card"
dd if=/dev/zero of=arch-rpi.img bs=1M count=1850

echo "Partitioning"
fdisk arch-rpi.img <<EOF
o
n
p
1

+100M

t
c
n
p
2


w
EOF

sleep 5

losetup -f arch-rpi.img
sleep 5

echo "Formatting vfat"
mkfs.vfat /dev/loop0p1
sleep 5
mkdir boot
echo "Mounting boot"
mount /dev/loop0p1 boot
echo "Installing"

echo "Formatting ext4"
mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop0p2
sleep 5
mkdir root
echo "Mounting root"
mount /dev/loop0p2 root

wget http://archlinuxarm.org/os/ArchLinuxARM-rpi-latest.tar.gz
echo "Installing"
bsdtar -xpf ArchLinuxARM-rpi-latest.tar.gz -C root
sync
mv root/boot/* boot
sync
umount boot root
losetup -d /dev/loop0p1
losetup -d /dev/loop0p1
losetup -d /dev/loop0
echo "All complete, image arch-rpi.img created, compressing...."
zip -9 arch-rpi.img.zip arch-rpi.img
```

I'm doing this on my Raspberry Pi - Raspbian Wheezy. And when it gets to the line `mkfs.vfat /dev/loop0p1` It says there's no such file / directory. I've read enough on Linux to know I'm trying to mount the .img as a loop device and then use mkfs to prepare the image for the tarball, but I don't quite know why loop0p# files are not there, they are listed by `fdisk -l`. What do I need to to in order to get this script I found working?

Comment: Did you read the comment right there in the script you pasted about loop.max_part in the kernel command line?

Comment: @psusi - [this is you](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.parted.devel/3650), huh? And [this too](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.parted.devel/3651)? Those were the threads that lead me to [this patchset](https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/8/15/185). I knew the comments at the top there were wrong - because I've been doing it for years. But I didn't know why. Thanks, man.

Comment: @mikeserv, yes, I have made sure parted will work correctly either way, but if you want fdisk to work right, then you need to boot with the loop.max_part kernel command line argument mentioned in the script comments.  Or you can run `partprobe` after `fdisk` to update the kernel.

Comment: @psusi - or `partx -u` or `losetup -P` - those are userspace scans that instruct the kernel to update the partition table. You dont need boot-parameters and a reboot to find a partition - you just need to scan for it.

Comment: @mikeserv, yea, `partx` works as an alternative to `partprobe`, but iirc, `losetup -P` also only works if you booted with the max_parts argument.

Comment: @psusi - that's not true. I have no such argument - and that API is deprecated anyway. `losetup -Pf file` will scan a loopfile for partitions. `man losetup` says *`--partscan` Force the kernel to scan the partition table on a newly created loop device.* You can try the example snippet in my answer below - there are arguments configured for that module in either my initramfs `/etc` or my root dir of the same name. Also, `modinfo` shows it is loaded with no parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `losetup -P` for creating a `-P`artitioned loop device, or else you need to partition the original loop device then `partx -u`pdate the kernel's partition table afterward. The `/dev/loop0p` devices will appear *after* the kernel recognizes that the partition has actually been partitioned. Probably this is partly what the intent behind the `sleep 5` is - but that should almost definitely be a `sync` - or both - instead.

Anyway, to demonstrate:

```
sudo sh -s <<\IN
    losetup -D                          
    fallocate "-l$((1024*1024*1024))" loop        
    printf %s\\n n '' '' '' ''  w y | gdisk loop
    sync; losetup -f loop
    lsblk /dev/loop*
IN
```

So the above sequence first `-D`etaches all current loop devices *(if any)* `fallocate`s a 1GB tmp file, writes a GPT partition table to it and does a single partition on it, then `sync`s the filesystem and assigns it to the `-f`irst available loop device before trying to list with `lsblk` all available loop devices. It prints:

```
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0   7:0    0   1G  0 loop
```

*But* if I alter the `losetup` line to read:

```
losetup -fP loop
```

...it instead prints:

```
NAME      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0       7:0    0    1G  0 loop 
├─loop0p1 259:0    0 1023M  0 loop 
└─loop0p2 259:1    0 1007K  0 loop
```

...because `losetup` first scans the backing file for a partition table. As you can see, it's not very good at it - rather than noting the extra 1M *(which is almost definitely the last iteration's partition table, actually)* as unallocated space it interprets it as a separate partition, but that's probably because I'm writing to a tmpfs *(twice in a row)* at the top of a 1GB file hole - working w/ actual data will be much more precise *(and zeroing the backing file as your script does w/ `dd` would handle that anyway)*. In any case - I can freely `mkfs.whatever` on the real partition there and afterwards `mount` it. `partx -u` on the `/dev/loop0` would achieve the same results.

Answer (score 3):

In the `loop` driver, support for partitions is optional, determined by the `max_part` argument when the driver is loaded. The default value is 0, so the loop driver won't even look for partitions; with a nonzero value, the driver supports that many partitions. Depending on the kernel build options, the driver may either be included in the kernel, in which case you need to pass `loop.max_part=…` on the kernel command line at boot time, or be loaded as a module, in which case you need to pass `max_part=…` when the module is loaded.

On Debian wheezy, `loop` is a module and the `max_part` argument is not passed. To get partition support, unload the module and load it back with a `max_part` argument (you'll need to first deactivate any existing loop device with `losetup -d`):

```
if lsmod | grep -wq loop; then rmmod loop; fi
modprobe loop max_part=31
```

You can make this the default by adding `options loop max_part=31` to `/etc/modprobe.conf`.

If you can't afford to unload the module (or to reboot, on a distribution where `loop` is built into the kernel), you can instead calculate the partition's offset manually and use the `-o` option to `losetup`. See
[Reading a filesystem from a whole disk image](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9099/reading-a-filesystem-from-a-whole-disk-image/9119#9119)

With newer distributions, [you can use `losetup -P` when setting up the loop device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187331):

```
…
losetup -P -f arch-rpi.img
…
```

but the `util-linux` package on Debian wheezy is too old to have this option.

Comment: This answer advocates a long deprecated kernel module parameter API in favor of a correctly versioned *(and simply installed)* `util-linux` package to match the asker's 3.18 kernel. The kernel has allowed for user-space scans for partitioned loop devices since kernel 3.1 *(wheezy's first kernel)* in 2011, and the `util-linux` tools the kernel devs ship w/ the kernel would likely benefit the asker far more than needless boot parameters. It is strange that this answer links to and quotes another answer in the same thread - but that other answer has only ever been voted on once - and it was down.